# using sed to convert numbers 0-9 to hex values from a large list

Tags: sed, hex

I have a 10,000,000 digit string of numbers. Numbers are not separated by anything, they are all crammed together like this (its a long string of the first 10,000,000 digits in pi):

```
1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

I'm trying to use sed to replace each number with a hex color value. Here's my code:

```
sed -e 's/0/#F5F5F5/' -e 's/1/#FFE4B5/' -e 's/2/#98FB98/' -e 's/3/#ADFF2F/' -e 's/4/#FF69B4/' -e 's/5/#BA55D3/' -e 's/6/#FF6347/' -e 's/7/#2E8B57/' -e 's/8/#8B4513/' -e 's/9/#000000/' < pi > pi2
```

trouble is, sed starts converting numbers from my hexcode substitutions. I want those conversions to stay untouched. How do I prevent that? Hope this is clear enough.

ending up with results like this:

```
#FFE#FF#FF634#2E#8B4513B57#000000B4B#BA55D34159#98FB986535897932384626433832795#F5F5F528841971693993751
```

Comment: Please clarify how the list is formatted (e.g. a list of numbers, each of which is 10 million digits or a list of 1 million ten-digit numbers totaling 10 million) and provide an example of a section of numbers before and after conversion, as you would like to see it. Is it like "1042" -> "#FFE4B5#F5F5F5#FF69B4#98FB98"?

Comment: yes, this is how i would like to see it: "1042" -> "#FFE4B5#F5F5F5#FF69B4#98FB98"

Comment: OK, I think "string" would be a better term than "list" since list seemed to imply multiple lines of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can stick with this approach if you add one sed command to the beginning and make a small change to each of your existing commands:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1,/g' -e 's/0,/#F5F5F5/g' -e 's/1,/#FFE4B5/g'  ...  < pi > pi2
```

1) Mark each integer in the input by following it with a comma.

2) When you do the substitution, only replace integers that are followed by a comma, and remove the comma when you're done with each one.

Also, as a bug fix, you should also add the `g` option on each substitution.

Comment: Alternately, you could start by converting the numbers to a letter range, then running the sed commands against the letters. For example: `sed -e 'y/0123456789/GHIJKLMNOP/' -e 's/G/#F5F5F5/g' -e 's/H/#FFE4B5/g'` ... performance probably isn't an issue here, but this keeps the original 10 million length rather than doubling it and then searches against a single character rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
LC_LANG=C sed -e 's/[0-9]/,_\1_,/g' <pi >pi2| sed -e 's/,_0_,/#F5F5F5/g;s/,_1_,/#FFE4B5/g .....'
```

and change the "delimiters" `,_` and `_,`  accordingly depending on the content of the file. (so that it never interfere with the content).
And maybe you need to add a space or ; after each color codes?... and maybe also a newline once in a while ^^

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $/=\1 }; s/0/#F5F5F5/ or s/1/#FFE4B5/ or s/2/#98FB98/ ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
   codes="F5F5F5 FFE4B5 98FB98 ADFF2F FF69B4 BA55D3 FF6347 2E8B57 8B4513 000000"
   split(codes,hex)
   FS=""
}
{  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      printf "#%s",hex[($i)+1]
   print ""
}

$ echo 1415 | awk -f tst.awk
#FFE4B5#FF69B4#FFE4B5#BA55D3

$ echo 1042 | awk -f tst.awk
#FFE4B5#F5F5F5#FF69B4#98FB98
```

The above just creates an array mapping numbers to the codes in the string and then for each digit on the input prints the string from the array. Awk arrays start at 1, not zero, hence adding 1 to $i.